# Converting datatypes for failing test function in Perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

Minimum code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.16;   
use Test::More tests => 2;

is_deeply(
[ [0, 0], [1, 0] ],
[ [0, 0], [1, 0] ],
'Intersects x-axis at (0, 0) and (1, 0)'
);   

is_deeply(
( [0, 0], [1, 0] ), 
( [0, 0], [1, 0] ),
'Intersects x-axis at (0, 0) and (1, 0)'
);
```

which returns

```
ok 1 - Intersects x-axis at (0, 0) and (1, 0)
is_deeply() takes two or three args, you gave 5.
This usually means you passed an array or hash instead 
of a reference to it at test44.pl line 14
not ok 2
#   Failed test at test44.pl line 14.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2 run.
```

The first code succeeds with `[[-,-],[-,-]]` entries but the second fails with `([-,-],[-,-])` entries. 
My function returns everything as `([-,-], [-,-])` which I want to test if it is on the x-axis.

There are too many args for the test, which is the reason why the test fails. 
So some conversion may be needed. 
However, my data chunks are very big so no duplication of data is not a good idea because of speed.

How can you proceed testing such data `([-,-],[-,-])` to fit the expected result efficiently?

Comment: Reading errors and warnings is part of being a programmer: "***you passed an array or hash instead of a reference to it***". Your tools are trying to help you, appreciate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use anonymous arrays, each one of them is interpreted as just 1 argument:

```
is_deeply(
          [ [0, 0], [1, 0] ],
          [ [0, 0], [1, 0] ],
          'Intersects x-axis at (0, 0) and (1, 0)'
);
```

The parentheses in the original code do nothing, the lists are flattened, i.e. the code is equivalent to

```
is_deeply( [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0],
           'Intersects x-axis at (0, 0) and (1, 0)'
);
```

5 arguments to `is_deeply`.

Comment: Simply `([-,-],[-,-])` to `[ ([-,-],[-,-]) ]` in the conversion.

Comment: And that's exactly what the error message told you.